# Use cases for CollectionDataContractAttribute?

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm working with an existing codebase and there are a lot of classes like:

```
[Serializable]
[CollectionDataContract
(
    Name = "DogList",
    ItemName = "Dog",
    Namespace = "Namespace"
)]
public class DogList : List<Dog>
{
}
```

According to the documentation I've found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850.aspx usage of this attribute isn't encouraged.

What would be the use case for writing code like this?  It looks redundant to me.

Answer (score 1):

from the cases I've seen in general use, its there to enforce a type on a collection. in your above example, if you omitted the attribute, then the runtime would serialize to `ArrayOfDogList`, and plenty of constructs can deserialize from `ArrayOf`, where as if you had the attribute, you *have* to deserialize to the DogList type, which would be somewhat restrictive, and as they say "compromises collection interchangeability".

I am a little surprised with your above example though. Most of the use cases I've seen would be more along the lines of

```
[CollectionDataContract(...)]
public class DogList : List<Dog> 
{ 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, typo, its not THAT odd. ;)

Comment: @jfar phew, as i was wondering where/why you'd use such a data structure. ok, so it all boils down to, if you dont have the attribute, its going to be an `ArrayOfDog` which can convert back into `Array`, `List` etc, where as with the attribute, you can only convert back to the `DogList` type. I've seen it used when you have a simple constructs PersonList : List<string> and AddressList : List<string>, as the type system would see both of these as `ArrayOfString`